# "Regarding" in Korean and Japanese

Tags: japanese, korean

To mark what is being regarded in Japanese is について (*nitsuite*), and in Korean, 에, but do these two concepts completely overlap?

> 돼지고기**에** 질렸어요.
>   I got tired of pork

Would a translation into Japanese use について? I ask because 에 seems like a 'weak' relationship marker, whereas 에 관하여 seems 'strong.' Is there a difference in Japanese?

Comment: It’s just “に.” “豚돼지肉고기に에.”

Answer (score 3):

No, Japanese would not use について because the verb to be used would be [**あきる**](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/2618/m0u/), see also [**here**](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E9%A3%BD%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B). The reason is that あきる requires the object to be marked with the case particle **-ni**:

```
私は豚肉に飽きた。
watashi-wa butaniku-ni aki-ta.
'I grew tired of pork.'
```

The expression について is often better translated as *about*:

```
私は言語学についての本を読んだ。
watashi-wa gengo-gaku-ni tsuite-no hon-o yon-da.
'I read a book about linguistics.'
```

The meaning *regarding* can also be expressed by [に関して](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AB%E9%96%A2%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6) and [に対して](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AB%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6).